# How can i get BLEdevice name using bluepy in Raspberrypi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to use the bluepy package to get the name of the surrounding bluetooth equipment without pairing.

I can get MAC address and RSSI value with device.addr and device.rssi but device.getValueText isn't working. (it returns None for all devices.)

how can i get BLE device name with bluepy packages?

'''
import numpy as np
from bluepy.btle import Scanner

def indexfinder():
time = 10

```
scanner = Scanner()
devices = scanner.scan(time)

MACaddr = np.zeros((10,2))

MACaddr[0][0] = ""
MACaddr[1][0] = ""
MACaddr[2][0] = ""
MACaddr[3][0] = ""
MACaddr[4][0] = ""
MACaddr[5][0] = ""
MACaddr[6][0] = ""
MACaddr[7][0] = ""
MACaddr[8][0] = ""
MACaddr[9][0] = ""
```

##### I need get BLE device name for this part

```
for device in devices:
    print("ADDR = {} RSSI = {}".format(device.addr, device.rssi))
    for i in range(10):
        if(device.addr == MACaddr[i][0]):
            MACaddr[i][1] = device.rssi * (-1)
            
minRSSI = 10000
minINDEX = 11



for k in range(10): 
    if(minRSSI < MACaddr[k][1]):
        minRSSI = MACaddr[k][1]
        minINDEX = k
        
return minRSSI, minINDEX
```

'''

Comment: Please post your code as text. Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.